# What are automatic destinations

Tags: windows-7

My AVG software started popping up cookies called "automatic destinations".  What are they?  Should I delete them or ignore them or add to exceptions??

Comment: Check in the internet options if "location" stuff is on (in Privacy Tab), change it and see if it changes. all cookies can be deleted, you could delete and observe. The only other Stuff on the web that comes up for it is some Add junk

Comment: There is indeed something called an _automatic destination_ in Windows NT 6.1.  The AVG user manual on its WWW site is silent upon this aspect (and indeed most other aspects) of the product, so it's unclear whether AVG is talking about the same thing.  Show us an example.

Comment: @JdeBP good thing your here, I searched further, and the term is applied in net tunneling, and redirection of files. and many other places, a Text of the cookie or even the address it belongs to would be interesting.